# `git shortlog`: Only count commits that have changed cpp files

Tags: git

`git shortlog -sne` can be used to get email addresses of all authors who have ever contributed to the project.

Is there a similarily fast command that only counts commits/shows authors that have modified actual source files (`*.cpp`, `*.h`, `*.py`, `*.cmake`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the paths:

```
git shortlog -sne -- '*.cpp' '*.h' '*.py' '*.cmake'
```

Quoting is necessary to prevent the shell from expanding the path names and have Git receive the `*` verbatim.